# Доступ к web-камере из Java

Tags: web-camera, java

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить доступ к web-камере с помощью Java. Хочется получить с камеры видео для обработки.
На всякий случай, web-камера Logitech c270.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берите обертку к OpenCV и наслаждайтесь.

[JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) или [OPENCV Processing and Java Library](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) или [OpenCV4Java](http://code.google.com/p/nativelibs4java/wiki/OpenCV)